# TYPO3 ke_search search results fr_CA language localisation

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a website installed with a locale fr_CA
The ke_search search results navigation is showing in english language.

The navigation widget in the list view code is e.g.:
typo3conf/ext/ke_search/Resources/Private/Templates/Widget/Pagination.html Line:99

```
<f:if condition="{pagination.next}">
    <li>
        <kesearch:link piVars="{page: pagination.next}" keepPiVars="1" class="next">{f:translate(key: 'LLL:EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_searchbox.xlf:pagebrowser_next')}</kesearch:link>
    </li>
</f:if>
```

I have tried multiple solutions :

1/ I try to override it with typoscript classic method

```
plugin.tx_kesearch._LOCAL_LANG.fr.pagebrowser_next = suivant
plugin.tx_kesearch._LOCAL_LANG.fr.pagebrowser_prev = précédent
```

2/ It try to override it with locallangXMLOverride :

```
// Override English with French Canadien language translation
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['fr_CA']
    ['EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_searchbox.xlf'][]
        = 'EXT:mytheme/Resources/Private/LanguageOverride/fr_CA.locallang_searchbox.xlf';
```

3/ I tried also to place this custom language file in the same language folder

4/ I tried to change locale to regular fr language and repeat the steps above. same thing for fr-CA and fr_ca.

None of the solutions above did work.

TYPO3 v12,
ke_search v5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I keep the locale fr_CA in the Sites conf. but in the xlf file target-language = "fr"

For the file name i used fr.locallang.*.

After that i made a low cache clear.

This worked for me, i hope it does for you.